# Azure - can't access VM from public ip

Tags: linux, azure, networking, nginx, cloud

I created a basic Linux VM machine; I can connect properly using SSH. I have already added http port 80 and https port 443 on the network rules but still can't access the machine from the browser using its public ip. The machine is running nginx.

I have tried dissociating and associating a new ip, with no luck, removing and re-adding rules with no luck.

I then created a new VM but instead of using a Basic VM I added a Standard VM and the only other difference is that I didn't enable the hi-avail option. I connected through ssh, added nginx, added the inbound rule in the network security group (http:80) and I can properly access it through the browser.

A lot of work has been done in the first VM before realizing that we can't access it through the browser, so it is not easy to do all the work from scratch. Here are my questions:

a) What could I be doing wrong so that access from the browser is not allowed? Here is a screenshot of my network security group:
[image]

b) Could the hi-availability option (hi-avail) cause the problem? I am afraid to delete it in case the VM stops working. bb) Can I delete this without issues?

c) Is there a way to transfer everything from the basic (hdd) VM to a standard (ssd) VM?

**edit:** concerning c) The reason I wanted to transfer was to change hardware, but it seems like it was easier than I thought. I just entered the VM 'Size' and changed CPU-RAM and concerning the HDD to SSD, on a stopped VM, I entered the disk and changed to Premium. That's about it.

Thank you in advance for your time. :/

Comment: Have you try to use reset ssh configure from azure new portal?

Comment: Comment from @mohitsharma : _I'm also facing the exact same problem. Do you find the solution of that?_

Comment: @kvantour It's been a long time since then and everything looks new to me right now, but check the discussion found hidden in the comments in the answer below, it might help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, this web service listening on port 8080, so we should add inbound rules in NSG, then use port 8080 to test it.

> Could the hi-availability option (hi-avail) cause the problem? I am
>   afraid to delete it in case the VM stops working.

As far as I know, in Azure resource module, we **can't** delete it.

> Is there a way to transfer everything from the basic (hdd) VM to a
>   standard (ssd) VM?

If you want to resize VM from basic to standard, we should copy VHD to SSD storage account, then use this VHD to create a standard VM.
We can use [Azcopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-use-azcopy) to do this.

After VHD copy complete, we can use PowerShell or [template](https://github.com/Azure/azure-quickstart-templates/tree/master/201-vm-specialized-vhd) to create new VM.

Comment: The problem is not with ssh, I can ssh properly. The problem is accessing port 80 using the public up through the browser.

Comment: Sorry, can you telnet this public IP with port 80?

Comment: can you access port 80 on this basic VM?  could you use `netstat -ant` command to list the port, and show it to me?

Comment: Telnet on port 80 gives connect:failed. On port 22 it connects properly as it should. Here are the results for the netstat command: http://imgur.com/a/zwFNk

Comment: @scooterlord listening on port 8080, so you should open port 8080 in NSG and use port 8080 to access it. Or change nginx default port to 80.

Comment: Sorry it took me so long to respond - was painting the house :/ . How could you tell that it's listening on port 8080? I enabled TCP/8080 in the settings and I am still getting unable to connect :/

Comment: Also, concerning the second half of the question.. about the transfer from a a basic system to a standard. I am not a system admin and having difficulties following what was said. Can anyone point me to a guide or provide more detailed guidelines? :/

Comment: Voted answer as correct - which probably is; you have already helped me quite much to pinpoint what the problem was (the nginx 8080 port) but would really like some more guidance concering the transfer of a basic vm to a standard one, if it's not too much to ask :>

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141480/discussion-between-jason-ye-msft-and-scooterlord).

Comment: I am online in chat!